# Unable to run dev

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, babeljs

I am currently taking a course on Udemy and I am stuck, I am having a problem running script. When I run the command npm run dev, I get this error message:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! forkify@1.0.0 dev: `webpack`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the forkify@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-01T10_10_11_136Z-debug.log
```

What would be wrong? This is my package.json code:

```
{
  "name": "forkify",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open"
  },
  "author": "Marv",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.28.4",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.14"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0"
  }
}
```

Here is the webpack.config.js code:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/js/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/js'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    mode: 'development' 
};
```

What could be wrong?

UPDATE: Some way I was able to finally `npm run dev` but it is being created in the wrong directory. How can I solve this?
[image]

I need it to appear under the `starter > dist > js`

Comment: Share webpack config file, the problem must come from there [Similar error with npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51720135/npm-run-script-error-on-windows)

Comment: Here is its'const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './starter/src/js/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/js'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    mode: 'development' 
};

Comment: Did you look in C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-01T10_10_11_136Z-debug.log ?

Comment: All seem be ok, verify your index.js path and webpack.config.js path are good

Comment: @seidohl yes, I have.

Comment: @AdrienLeloir it's in the js folder

Comment: @MarvellousAdesanya I really think the problem come from path, share picture of your webpack config + path

Comment: @AdrienLeloir I have successfully been able to create the bundle.js but it is being created in the wrong directory, I will share the image shortly.

Comment: @AdrienLeloir kindly check in the latest edit

Comment: I wrote the answer below, read webpack guide might be help you [webpack official guide](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/#basic-setup)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your path are not good replace `entry: './src/js/index.js'` by `entry: './started/src/js/index.js'`